# Adjective that describes a norm that is abided to 99% of the time

Tags: phrase-request

A "norm" is a behavior that is usual or expected. But there are different levels of norms: there are norms that e.g. 70% of the people abide to, and there are norms that 99% of the people abide to.

What is an adjective or an adjectival phrase that describes a norm of the second type - a norm that almost all people behave by?

The number "99%" is only an example. I would like to say something like:

> The X norm in computer science is...

where "X" is an adjective that emphasizes that this norm is abided to by most people in computer science.

Comment: I don't think that a behaviour pattern flouted by 30% of the population could reasonably be called the "norm". That's to say I'd normally only refer to some pattern as the norm if the *vast* majority both expected and observed it. And arguing about whether that's 95% or 99% of the total population seems pointless to me. But I suppose you could emphasize it with, say, [***near-universal** norm*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22near-universal+norm%22).

Comment: Statisticians use the terms _distribution_ and [_standard deviation_](https://www.mathsisfun.com/data/standard-normal-distribution.html) to describe this phenomonon, although those labels are typically used to describe statistical measures, as opposed to "usual behaviors."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the phrase that matches what you want to express best is the one FumbleFingers mentioned in his comment - **near-universal norm**, which means almost every single member of a group follows that "rule".

Here is an example from [a paper about the evolution of norms](http://journals.plos.org/plosbiology/article?id=10.1371/journal.pbio.0030194)

> **Then there are the near-universal norms,** such as the rules against most types of physical assault or theft within groups that, although they vary in their specifics, are interpreted as necessary to preserve functional societies.

An alternative is **standard practice**.

> One of the standard practices for effective DevOps is automated regression testing.

A standard practice has the connotation of a process that has turned out to be effective, so a lot of people use it. It isn't a strong as "near-universal" in terms of how many people follow the practice, but it can imply that the people who follow that practice do a better job than the people who don't.

Answer (score 1):

It depends how specific you want to be, a description like

> **almost all the time**

would give a **range** of possibilities.

The first thing that comes to mind are the adjectival phrases

> **ninety-nine percent of the time
>
>   *99% of the population*
>
>   all but one percent of the time**
>   *something* **falls within three standard deviations** *(99.7%)*

would give you 99% without ambiguity.

However, there is no **norm** (normal) that I know of which is exclusively **99% of the time**

> **as certain as death and taxes**

is considered to be 100% of the time.